# Problem using scipy.interpolate.interp2d. The code takes too long to execute

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a text file with three columns. The first are X positions, the second Y positions and the third values of a variable of X and Y. I want to interpolate it. However, when I run the code, the time it takes is too long. I have let it run for 10 straight minutes before stoping execution and it hasn't worked. I have constructed a similar code in mathematica and it only takes 10 seconds and does more stuff.

I read the text file and give the values to X, Y and f(X, Y) as

```
f = open('XdataTXT.txt','r')
linesX=f.readlines()
X_column_number = 0
positionX=[]
Y_column_number = 1
positionY=[]
VarX_column_number=2
varX=[]
for x in linesX:
    positionX.append(float(x.split()[X_column_number]))
    positionY.append(float(x.split()[Y_column_number]))
    varX.append(float(x.split()[VarX_column_number]))
f.close()
```

Once I have these three vectors I try to follow [this example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) in which a similar thing is done. There, the values of the function f(x, y) are assigned and then, the interpolation is performed.

My code is as follows

```
windXInterpFunc = interpolate.interp2d(positionX, positionY, windX, kind='cubic')
```

I have also attempted to transpos the vectors, but it doesn't work either.

```
positionXT=np.reshape(positionX, 42441)
positionYT=np.reshape(positionY, 42441)
windXT=np.reshape(windX, 42441)
```

Can someone please tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you able to identify which lines are taking a long time to run? (Including your calls to `reshape`.)

Comment: The reshape is almost instantaneous, it doesn't even takes one second. The issue is the next line `windXInterpFunc = interpolate.interp2d(positionXT, positionYT, windXT, kind='cubic')`

Comment: The `reshape` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) says that the storage of the reshaped array is not guaranteed to be contiguous and will be a new view if possible. Could you either let us know what python `type` the positionXT variable is, or try constructing a numpy or python `array` directly, rather than using a native python list? Perhaps the underlying storage is slow. Also, the interp2d documentation mentions that RectBivariateSpline is much faster if your x and y are a grid (or can be massaged into one).

Comment: The type of positionXT is a `numpy.ndarray`. Thanks for the suggestion on RectBivariateSpline. However, if I write `windXInterpFunc = interpolate.interp2d(positionXT, positionYT, windXT, kind='RectBivariateSpline')` a faillure occurs `raise ValueError("Unsupported interpolation type.")`

Comment: I'm a little late to be useful, but in case anybody else needs help with interp2d, I'd recommend plotting your function in 3D space first and seeing if it seems reasonably interpolate-able: 
`fig = plt.figure()`
`ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')`
`ax.plot_surface(positionX, positionY, windX)`
(You will need to reshape your arrays to be 2d first)